# Accidently renamed system/xbin to system/xbi

Tags: samsung

So i accidently renamed xbin in /system to xbi. I can't get root anymore because su is stored there and it won't work in xbi. I get a 'Connection to ui timed out' every time i try do './su'. If it helps i'm on a Samsung S4 Mini or a GT-I9195T.

Answer (score 2):

Someone will probably want an answer so here are the steps I performed:

I managed to get twrp running on it with odin. (I got odin from odindownload.com, gone to twrp.me/Devices), found my device, grabbed the `.tar` and started odin.

I then clicked the 'AP' button and selected the `.tar` file. I connected the phone and pressed start. Booted into recovery by holding the

<kbd>Vol up</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> +  <kbd>Power key</kbd> buttons.

Finally I hopped in a terminal and finally `cd system;mv xbi xbin`.